# Block Data URI scripts in html file

Tags: javascript, html

How can I block a Data URI script like this but don't affect any other script?

[image]

Comment: care to explain yourself?

Comment: In [this](http://skillgun.com/cpp/interview-questions-and-answers/paper/271) site, that's script disable my rightclick, I can't copy anything. That's why I want to block it.